# How to read maximum precision values from an Oracle database using Entity Framework 4?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, oracle10g

I have a `FLOAT(126)` column that was mapped to a `Decimal` by the Entity Framework. It works both for writing and reading, except in one case.

When I write a high precision value such as:

`1m / 3m = 0.33333333333333333333333333333333`

I can't read it, the framework throws an `ArithmeticOverflowException`.

How to solve that? My temporary solution is to round the number to 6 decimal places before inserting them. But what if I required the full precision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal only support 28-29 significant digits ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx ) and since EF doesn't support custom type mapping like NHibernate does - it's not possible to load more than the type can handle.

I don't know if it occurs to you but by converting a decimal to float you are losing precision and as you can see you end up with the quirky rounding that floats have. You really should be using decimal instead of float if you are after precision and also set the max significant digits to the max of decimal.

Comment: Okay, I removed the 38-digit part. The problem is: if the value was a Decimal before inserted in the database, why can't it be retrieved? I guess all extra precision was removed when it was cast to a decimal in the first place

Comment: It has to do with how floats are represented. I can't give you an correct example of the top of my had but say that 3.8 converted and stored to float is actually has to actually be stored as 3.7999999999999999999999999 until basically you run out of significant digits. There are plenty of very detailed explanations on the float representations on the internet - just google for float and you will hit many, but they are not very easy to read.